# IE 8, 9, and 10 won't load my Facebook like box in an iframe

Tags: facebook-likebox

I use the following newly generated Facebook like box html (added https:) on my webpage myhcdp.com:

```
  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?
  href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FHendersonCountyDems&amp;width=292
  &amp;height=950&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true
  &amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true&amp;appId=120437058037420"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;
  width:290px; height:950px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

It loads correctly in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11, but IE 8, 9, and 10 give me "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error panel.  If I copy the src string (https:...appid=...) and open it directly in another tab, IE 8, 9, and 10 open it just fine.

I have tried fixes I found in other posts on stackoverflow, such as changing &amp; to &.  Also changed %hex to actual characters (: and /).  Modified iframe code still worked in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11, and still did not work in IE 8, 9, and 10.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after much searching, I found another stackoverflow post that mentioned disabling avast! IE addon.  Presto, my like box started loading in IE!